# jquery not returning what I want

Tags: php, jquery

I've been doing well with all the Jquery so far but I've now run across a problem when I try to pull data from another php file... I'm just testing it out with one piece of data before I write in the rest of the data and I'm glad because its not working

This is my jquery that gets the information

```
$.post('php/getinfo.php', {}, function(data){
//Fill variables
var lvl1v = $('#lvl1vocab').text(data);
//Set div's to variables
$('#1v').text(lvl1v);
}, "html");
```

This is all that is on my getinfo.php page at the moment

```
<div id="lvl1vocab">120</div>
```

what I do get written to the screen instead of "120" is "[object Object]"

Comment: Well then `data` is obviously not a string value, but an object …

Comment: So you're asking how to write the contents of an `object` to the screen?

Comment: You need to access your object. ie: `data[0]` or similar. we would need to see the output of `object` to help you.

Comment: I want the text in that div tag from getphp.php to appear on my main screen when I'm hovered over an object

Comment: Please provide in your question the output of your object.

Comment: I honestly don't know how to do that...

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
var lvl1v = $('#lvl1vocab').text(data);
```

is looking for the `lvl1vocab` ID in the current DOM, not in the data returned from the server. You should do:

```
var lvl1v = $(data).text();
```

to get the text of the top-level element in the returned data.

To be able to search for things in the returned data, use:

```
var $data = $('<div>', { html: data }); // Wrap another DIV around it
var lvl1v = $data.find('#lvl1vocab').text();
```

You need the extra DIV wrapper because `find()` won't match the top-level element it's given, just its descendants.

Comment: Ok that works! but I'm going to have about 15 pieces of information on that page how do I make it grab that specific DIV?

This is what I found by searching 
`var mainDiv = $("#mainDiv", data);`
and made it fit my names but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Things would be much easier if you returned JSON instead of HTML. You should only return HTML if you just want to insert the returned result directly into the DOM, not search it for things.

Comment: I don't know JSON at all, my knowledge is actually mostly in MySQL it has been a while since I've done PHP and Jquery need to get into it more again! 

Thanks for the help and explanations!

Comment: Do a little studying. You'll see that returning JSON is much easier than returning HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like all you have to do is this:

```
$.post('php/getinfo.php', {}, function(data){
$('#1v').html(data);
}, "html");
```

This is assuming your full value of data is `<div id="lvl1vocab">120</div>` and you want to put the div from your return value into your #1v div

This is your output:

```
<div id="1v">
  <div id="lvl1vocab">120</div>
</div>
```

If you are planning on returning multiple div's in your data and they need to be split up and put into further divs already parsed to the page then you need to look into returning an object using json_encode php side and having a look at datatypes on the jQuery page: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/